# How to Ignore specflow test using programing

Tags: specflow

I want to execute specflow scenario based on some condition and skip test if condition is not met programmatically.

I have created one test which gets executed for different countries, but I want to execute test only for one country not all.

I tried scenariocontext.current.pending(); In this case steps are getting skipped but in Jenkins, test result is shown as failed.

Comment: It sounds like you want to filter your tests. Can you provide more information about what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Since SpecFlow 3.1 you can do it with the UnitTestRuntimeProvider.

```cs
    [Binding]
    public sealed class StepDefinitions
    {
        private readonly IUnitTestRuntimeProvider _unitTestRuntimeProvider;

        public CalculatorStepDefinitions(IUnitTestRuntimeProvider unitTestRuntimeProvider)
        {
            _unitTestRuntimeProvider = unitTestRuntimeProvider;
        }

        [When("your binding")]
        public void YourBindingMethod()
        {
            _unitTestRuntimeProvider.TestIgnore("This scenario is always skipped");
        }
    }
```

Ignoring is like skipping the scenario. Be careful, as it behaves a little bit different for the different unit test runners (xUnit, NUnit, MSTest, SpecFlow+ Runner).

Also, this works only in step definitions. It is not possible to use it in hooks.